# Does the headquarters of the Democratic National Committee have a museum or is it just offices?

Tags: united-states, campaigning, democratic-party

I have only seen photographs of the exterior of the headquarters of the Democratic National Committee in Washington. What is it like inside? Is there a museum? Is it opened to the public, or is it just offices for workers?

Answer (score 4):

It is not advertised as a tourist attraction.  There is nothing on their web pages that invite casual visits. It is not mentioned on external tourist websites. I found a couple of "local knowledge" websites that recommend on which floor you can get coffee, but that is for employees or researchers, not for tourists.

I conclude that it is a workspace, with offices and conference rooms. It does not house a public museum nor is it generally open to the public.